# CSCart Custom Block Template

Tags: javascript, block, cs-cart

I'm trying to separate tabs from `template/blocks/product_templates/default_template.tpl` on cscart. My goal will result to having 2 templates above and below: the `default_template.tpl` and add a custom block for tabs. I created a custom HTML with Smarty. Here's the code block:

```
{capture name="val_hide_form"}{/capture}
{capture name="val_capture_options_vs_qty"}{/capture}
{capture name="val_capture_buttons"}{/capture}
{capture name="val_no_ajax"}{/capture}

{include file="views/tabs/components/product_popup_tabs.tpl"}
{$smarty.capture.popupsbox_content nofilter}

{include file="views/tabs/components/product_tabs.tpl"}

{if $blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper}
    {include file=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper content=$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content title=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.description}
{else}
    {$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content nofilter}
{/if}
```

It pulls up the HTML, but it does not recognize the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the tabs in a capture variable in file default_template.tpl

```
{capture name="product_details_tabs"}
...
{/capture}
```

and in a custom html smarty block to display it( but you need to have if under main content block )

```
{$smarty.capture.product_details_tabs nofilter}
```

## layout blocks should be looking like this

[image: layout blocks should be looking like this]

example of capture in default_template.tpl file:

## before

```
{if $show_product_tabs}

    {include file="views/tabs/components/product_tabs.tpl"}

    {if $blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper}
        {include file=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper content=$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content title=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.description}
    {else}
        {$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content nofilter}
    {/if}

{/if}
```

## after

```
{if $show_product_tabs}

{capture name="product_details_tabs"}

    {include file="views/tabs/components/product_tabs.tpl"}

    {if $blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper}
        {include file=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.properties.wrapper content=$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content title=$blocks.$tabs_block_id.description}
    {else}
        {$smarty.capture.tabsbox_content nofilter}
    {/if}

{/capture}

{/if}
```

I hope that helps,